# Ajax, same code but my version is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xml

So right now I am doing the Web Development Masterclass - Complete Certificate Course on Udemy by YouAccel Training. In the final project, there is some Ajax in JQuery that is not working properly with my version, but if I copy the downloaded code from the course it works fine. I used several text comparing apps and really the only difference is the text in the `<div>`. What could be the problem?

My version:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#contact").click(function () {

            fname = $("#fname").val();
            email = $("#email").val();
            message = $("#message").val();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "sendmsg.php",
                data: "fname=" + fname + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
                success: function (html) {
                    if (html == 'true') {

                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-success"> \
                                         <strong>Message Sent!</strong> \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'fname_long') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>First Name</strong> cannot exceed 50 characters. \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'fname_short') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>First Name</strong> must be more than 2 characters. \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'email_long') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Email Address</strong> is too long. \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'email_short') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Email Address</strong> must be longer than 2 characters. \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'eformat') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Email</strong> format incorrect. \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'message_long') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Message</strong> cannot exceed 50 characters. \ \ 
                                         </div>');

                    } else if (html == 'message_short') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Message</strong> must be longer than 2 characters. \ \ 
                                         </div>');


                    } else {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                             <strong>Error</strong> processing request. Try again! \ \ 
                                             </div>');
                    }
                },
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#add_err2").html("loading...");
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
```

The original code:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#contact").click(function () {

        fname = $("#fname").val();
        email = $("#email").val();
        message = $("#message").val();

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "sendmsg.php",
            data: "fname=" + fname + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
            success: function (html) {
                if (html == 'true') {

                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-success"> \
                                         <strong>Message Sent!</strong> \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'fname_long') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>First Name</strong> must cannot exceed 50 characters. \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'fname_short') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>First Name</strong> must exceed 2 characters. \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'email_long') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Email</strong> must cannot exceed 50 characters. \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'email_short') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Email</strong> must exceed 2 characters. \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'eformat') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Email</strong> format incorrect. \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'message_long') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Message</strong> must cannot exceed 50 characters. \ \
                                         </div>');

                } else if (html == 'message_short') {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Message</strong> must exceed 2 characters. \ \
                                         </div>');


                } else {
                    $("#add_err2").html('<div class="alert alert-danger"> \
                                         <strong>Error</strong> processing request. Please try again. \ \
                                         </div>');
                }
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $("#add_err2").html("loading...");
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Which div? or do we need to also do the compare?

Comment: Have you checked the errors on the browser console? They could point in the right direction? Right click on the page and select 'Inspect'

Comment: In your code, as pasted, you've done `\[space]` while they've done `\[newline]` - never use `\\ ` to extend a line in javascript, close the line with `'` and start the next one with `+ '`

Comment: So, in their code then have `"<div>[escaped newline]</div>"` while yours has `"<div>[escaped space][newline]</div>"` - as you can't have (unescaped) newlines in the middle of text, your script fails with error: `Invalid or unexpected token` - check the browser console for errors.

Comment: @freedomn-m Thank you for the profound answer, it really returns with invalid or unexpected token, however I don't really understand the difference. I try to find it but it just looks the same.

Comment: So as you said I figured that the problem is not syntactical in a way that the only problem is copying it. I am not sure about the difference but I will definitely look it up, thanks for the help!

Comment: Is the name of the document that contains the above javascript also called `sendmsg.php`? That is: is the PHP code that returns true/false also located at the top of *the same document that contains the javascript*? Or is the PHP code in a separate file?

Comment: The php code is in a different file. The problem was that the '\ \' characters were copied and had "<div>[escaped space][newline]</div>" instead of "<div>[escaped newline]</div>".